# Какой максимальный размер у локальной базы данных mysql?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Какой максимальный размер у локальной базы данных mysql?

Comment: Лимит на одну таблицу, по-видимому, [256ТБ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-limits.html). Лимита при [неограниченном числе баз/таблиц](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/database-count-limit.html) можно считать что нет.

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, а, скажите ещё, где хранятся данные таблиц локальной БД? в памяти компьютера, или где-то на серверах MySQL? хотелось бы разобраться в этом вопросе.

Comment: Они хранятся по тому пути, который вы указали в опции `datadir` в настройках mysql-сервера

Comment: @andreymal я уже не помню, какой путь я указывал.
подскажите, где его можно уточнить

Comment: Где-то в файле настроек `my.cnf` где-то в том месте, куда вы установили MySQL (если у вас винда, то вероятно где-то в C:\ProgramData)